# SQL to display data of current month & next month from table

Tags: sql, database, oracle-sqldeveloper

I wanted some guidance on producing an SQL query that collects the table information of the current date and also next month without having to type in every day for the current month being October or the next month being November.

Basically I've got a table called WORK, in this table there are SHIFTID, DATEOFSHIFT, and MEMBERSHIPID. I basically need to list the SHIFTID's of shifts where MEMBERSHIPID = null and where DATEOFSHIFT is in November (next month)

Then I need to produce a query for the shift roster showing SHIFTID, DATEOFSHIFT, and MEMBERSHIPID of each shift in this current month.

This is the structure of my database table if needed.

[image]

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend:

```
select w.*
from work w
where w.membershipid is null and
      w.dateofshift >= trunc(sysdate, 'Month') + interval '1' month and
      w.dateofshift < trunc(sysdate, 'Month') + interval '2' month;
```

You can also phrase the `where` as:

```
where w.membershipid is null and
      trunc(w.dateofshift, 'Month') >= trunc(sysdate, 'Month') + interval '1' month
```

but this makes it hard for Oracle to use an index if an appropriate one is available.

Answer (score 0):

Well from what you've provided, I infer that you want a query to display the information on all those fields for the current month. That is achievable by:

```
Select SHIFTID, DATEOFSHIFT, MEMBERSHIPID
From WORK
Where Month(DATEOFSHIFT)=MONTH(GETDATE());
```

Comment: If using Oracle you can use the following syntax:
Select SHIFTID, DATEOFSHIFT, MEMBERSHIPID
From WORK
Where Extract(month from DATEOFSHIFT)=EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSTIMESTAMP);